# How to use different Kotlin versions for modules in Android Studio (WearOS module)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I have an Android project with several modules, the phone app module and some library modules. They all work with CoposeCompiler 1.2.0 and Kotlin version 1.7.0. Now, I'd like to add a WearOS module to create an app for smartwatches using JetpackCompose as well. The problem is that the latest stable version of ComposeCompiler for WearOS (1.1.1) does need Kotlin 1.6.10 to work, and won't build without that version.

I've tried to add Kotlin 1.6.10 as a dependency along with the existing one (1.7.0), but it thows an error when I try to build the project (duplicate classes). I did it in project-level Gradle file and module-level Gradle file.

I also tried to use the `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true` tag inside `kotlinOptions` for WearOS module, but it also thows an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.isInline()'
```

I don't know how could I achive that. The only option that I seem fasible is to create another project specifically for the WearOS app, but I'd like to have all the modules together in a single project. Any help will be welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was: **How to use different Kotlin versions for different modules in the same project?**

I will give an answer how I solved this problem.

Example scenario, there are 2 modules :app and :module.

:app needs to use Kotlin version 1.8.0
:module needs to use Kotlin version 1.6.2

Remove from your top-level build.gradle plugin block:

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.0" apply false
}
```

Add a buildscript block to :app module's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        // mavenCentral() include if you need plugins from other repositories
        // google() include if you need plugins from other repositories
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"
        // other plugin dependencies...
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
```

Add a buildscript block to :module build.gradle and specify kotlin version:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        // mavenCentral() include if you need plugins from other repositories
        // google() include if you need plugins from other repositories
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.2"
        // other plugin dependencies...
    }
} 

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
```

That's it. Now, you :module will be built using 1.6.2 and :app with 1.8.0

Comment: you really just churned this out from chat-GPT, huh...

Answer (score 2):

Acccording to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/compose#compat): "Using version 1.0 of Compose for Wear OS requires using version 1.2 of androidx.compose libraries and Kotlin 1.7.0." This is slightly out of date but basically WearOS 1.1.1 does not need Kotlin 1.6.10.

Try this:

```
        kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
        wear_compose_version = '1.1.1'
        compose_version = '1.3.3'
        compose_compiler_version = '1.4.0'
```

Comment: This is correct, but out of date. The compose sample is already using Kotlin 1.8 and Compose Compiler 1.4.0

https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/main/ComposeStarter/gradle/libs.versions.toml

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just could find the correct version "mixture" for it to work with my existing libraries. It appeared that I was using a too old compiler version, but I managed to do it now.

Comment: It does not answer the question: how to use different Kotlin versions in for different modules in the same project, I stumbled across the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner and more up-to-date solution would be to keep using the Gradle plugins DSL and not add `buildscript` to the module's build.gradle.
In order to use different Kotlin versions you will need:

1. Remove from top-level build.gradle:

   ```
   plugins {
       id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.0" apply false
   }
   ```
2. In one module's build.gradle add Kotlin 1.7.0:

   ```
   plugins {
       id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.0"
   }
   ```
3. In other module's build.gradle add Kotlin 1.6.10:

   ```
   plugins {
       id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.6.10"
   }
   ```

Note that in that case when a version of a plugin isn't specified in the top-level build.gradle you must set it in all modules' build.gradle.